# Combing the NLTK text features with sklearn Vectorized features

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn, nltk, feature-extraction

I am trying to combine the dict type features used in NLTK along with the SKLEARN tfidf feature for each instance.

Sample Input:
instances=[["I am working with text data"],["This is my second sentence"]]
instance = "I am working with text data "

```
    def generate_features(instance):
        featureset["suffix"]=tokenize(instance)[-1]
        featureset["tfidf"]=self.tfidf.transform(instance)
        return features

    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegressionCV
    from nltk.classify.scikitlearn import SklearnClasskifier
    self.classifier = SklearnClassifier(LogisticRegressionCV())
    self.classifier.train(feature_sets)
```

This tfidf is trained on all the instances. But when I train the nltk classifier using this featureset it throws the following error.

```
self.classifier.train(feature_sets)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/classify/scikitlearn.py", line 115, in train
X = self._vectorizer.fit_transform(X)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site
packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/dict_vectorizer.py", line 226, in fit_transform
return self._transform(X, fitting=True)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/dict_vectorizer.py", line 174, in _transform
values.append(dtype(v))
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

I understand the issue here, that it cannot vectorize the already vectorized features. But is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: please provide sample data to reproduce your issue

Answer (score 0):

For those who might visit this question in future, I did the following thing which solved the issue.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegressionCV
from scipy.sparse import hstack

def generate_features(instance):
    featureset["suffix"]=tokenize(instance)[-1]
    return features

feature_sets=[(generate_features(instance),label) for instance in instances]
X = self.vec.fit_transform([item[0] for item in feature_sets]).toarray()
Y = [item[1] for item in feature_sets]
tfidf=TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform(instances)

X=hstack((X,tfidf))
classifier=LogisticRegressionCV()
classifier.fit(X,Y)
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if it's help or not. In my case, featureset["suffix"]'s values must be string or number. For example :

> featureset["suffix"] = "some value"